# Sql group items with same value in same table in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

[image of resource table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWZbY.png)

The above image is an image of a resource table of a site am building an android app for. Please sorry for my bad english and poor explanation, i will try to explain to the best i can. i have a table called resources as show below and it is part of another table called product. Product table is where the information about the product is stored while resource table is where images name and storage direction is stored. Each image has a seperate line. now if i try to run a query to link or join the product and resource table i start getting duplicated / repeated output values because of the images of the resources.

**below is the product table**

```
  pk_i_id | fk_i_user_id | p_name | p_description |  etc
    1       4              iphone     Iphone X  
    2       4              Cloth      Gucci     
    3       6              watch      Rolex Watch   
    4       3              car        Venza     
    5       7              tractor    CAT   
    6       9              Fruits     Melon
```

**below is the resource table**

```
pk_i_id | fk_i_item_id | s_name | s_extension | s_content_type | s_path
    1     2             xDSDki0F    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    2     2             GAsk8vqW    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    3     3             D033Znu1    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    4     3             yZSPKeCj    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    5     5             rc8wCLOQ    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    6     5             tUWBh6vk    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    8     6             v3rSPl9s    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    9     7             8FTuKvgl    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    10    7             fzb2KzYq    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    11    7             9Qs7MgUl    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    12    8             3HmpjxC7    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    13    8             VF4M6PrE    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    14    8             tnIH7LqU    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    15    8             M5jKALrD    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
    16    9             vBBSSfoD    jpg         image/jpeg       oc-content/uploads/0/
```

if i do a Query like this

```
select * products p, resource r where p.pk_i_id=r.fk_i_item_id
```

It will give me Multiple repeated Query due to multiple section of resource image storage. if Image about Car is 3 the query will display repeated query of car three times.

Judging from the above table if i try to fetch from here using this below Query"

```
select * from osoe_t_item_resource
```

it will display all those above table value in the app.

Please i need a query that will group the items with the same fk_i_item_id as another column example

instead of appearing like this output below

```
{"NewsApp":[
{"pk_i_id":"1","fk_i_item_id":"2","s_name":"xDSDki0F
{"pk_i_id":"2","fk_i_item_id":"2","s_name":"GAsk8vqW
{"pk_i_id":"3","fk_i_item_id":"3","s_name":"D033Znu1"},
{"pk_i_id":"4","fk_i_item_id":"3","s_name":"yZSPKeCj"},
{"pk_i_id":"5","fk_i_item_id":"5","s_name":"rc8wCLOQ"},
{"pk_i_id":"6","fk_i_item_id":"5","s_name":"tUWBh6vk"},
{"pk_i_id":"8","fk_i_item_id":"6","s_name":"v3rSPl9s"},
{"pk_i_id":"9","fk_i_item_id":"7","s_name":"8FTuKvgl"},
{"pk_i_id":"10","fk_i_item_id":"7","s_name":"fzb2KzYq"},
{"pk_i_id":"11","fk_i_item_id":"7","s_name":"9Qs7MgUl"},
{"pk_i_id":"12","fk_i_item_id":"8","s_name":"3HmpjxC7"},
{"pk_i_id":"13","fk_i_item_id":"8","s_name":"VF4M6PrE"},
{"pk_i_id":"14","fk_i_item_id":"8","s_name":"tnIH7LqU"},
{"pk_i_id":"15","fk_i_item_id":"8","s_name":"M5jKALrD"},
{"pk_i_id":"16","fk_i_item_id":"9","s_name":"vBBSSfoD"},
{"pk_i_id":"17","fk_i_item_id":"9","s_name":"kUt65zVb"},
{"pk_i_id":"18","fk_i_item_id":"9","s_name":"D5DXAszv"},
```

it should appear like this output

```
{"NewsApp":[
{"pk_i_id":"1","fk_i_item_id":"2","s_name":"xDSDki0F","s_name2":"GAsk8vqW"},
{"pk_i_id":"3","fk_i_item_id":"3","s_name":"D033Znu1","s_name2":"yZSPKeCj"},
{"pk_i_id":"5","fk_i_item_id":"5","s_name":"rc8wCLOQ","s_name2":"tUWBh6vk"},
{"pk_i_id":"8","fk_i_item_id":"6","s_name":"v3rSPl9s"},
{"pk_i_id":"9","fk_i_item_id":"7","s_name":"8FTuKvgl","s_name2":"fzb2KzYq","s_name3":"9Qs7MgUl"},
{"pk_i_id":"12","fk_i_item_id":"8","s_name":"3HmpjxC7"},
{"pk_i_id":"13","fk_i_item_id":"8","s_name":"VF4M6PrE","s_name2":"tnIH7LqU","s_name":"M5jKALrD"},
{"pk_i_id":"16","fk_i_item_id":"9","s_name2":"vBBSSfoD"},
{"pk_i_id":"17","fk_i_item_id":"9","s_name":"kUt65zVb","s_name2":"D5DXAszv"},
```

If you watch closely all times with the same id has be merged together in one out,

Please help me out.

Comment: SQL SELECT statements have a JOIN component that you use for joining multiple tables. Please format the question a bit better. JSON encoding of the output should be done by you application rather than the web server.

Comment: or how can i get output of only the first image of the rows

Comment: the web server do the JSON encoding and the places it to desired locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understant that, when there are records with the same `fk_i_item_id`, you want to keep only one, which has the lowest `pk_i_id`.

If you are using MySQL 8.0, this is straightforward with window function `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT x.pk_i_id, x.fk_i_item_id, x.s_name
FROM (
    SELECT
        r.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.fk_i_item_id ORDER BY r.pk_i_id) rn
    FROM resource r
) x WHERE x.rn = 1
```

The inner query ranks each record within `fk_i_item_id` groups, and the outer query filters out duplicates.

---

If you are running an earlier version of MySQL, you can use a `NOT EXIST` condition with a correlated subquery that ensures that no other record exists with the same `fk_i_item_id` and a lower `pk_i_id` :

```
SELECT r.pk_i_id, r.fk_i_item_id, r.s_name
FROM resource r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM resource r1 
    WHERE r1.fk_i_item_id = r.fk_i_item_id AND r1.pk_i_id < r.pk_i_id
)
```

Comment: Wow thanks alot it worked like a charm. God bless you

Comment: Please how will i add the osoe_t_item table to the query to make i,pk_i_id=r.fk_i_item_id ?

Comment: `FROM resource r INNER JOIN osoe_t_item i ON i.pk_i_id=r.fk_i_item_id`...